# Nim return custom tuple containing proc

Tags: tuples, nim-lang

I'm trying to create a proc that returns a custom tuple that contains a single element that is a proc type i.e.

```
type
  CustomTuple = tuple
    foo: proc(input: int): int

proc createCustomTuple(): CustomTuple =
  (foo: proc(input: int): int = 10)
```

However, when I compile this I get the following error (I am compiling with Nim Version 1.2.6 on Windows).

> Error: type mismatch: got <tuple[foo: proc (input: int):
> int{.noSideEffect, gcsafe, locks: 0.}]> but expected 'CustomTuple =
> tuple[foo: proc (input: int): int{.closure.}]'

So the compiler thinks I am returning a regular tuple and not a `CustomTuple` but I have no idea how to change this to make it work. The documentation for tuples in the [Nim manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-tuples-and-object-types) show custom tuples being constructed in the way that I am doing it and I couldn't find any examples of returning a custom tuple from a proc.

If I change my `CustomTuple` definition to contain types that aren't procs then it compiles successfully so it appears it has something to do my custom tuple containing a proc that is causing this to fail to compile.

Can anyone explain why the above code is not compiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason my original code isn't working is because Nim is unable to convert the proc to a closure automatically when it is added to a tuple. [There is some discussion around this in the Nim forums.](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/6117)

As the proc is not converted to a closure the compiler is unable to determine that the tuple being returned is a `CustomTuple` because the types don't match which explains the error message.

So when packing a proc in a tuple you need to explicitly convert it to a closure. This  can be done by explicitly casting the proc like this:

```
type
  CustomTuple = tuple
    foo: proc(input: int): int

proc createCustomTuple(): CustomTuple =
  (foo: (proc(input:int):int)(proc(input: int): int = 10))
```

or by adding a `{.closure.}` pragma like this (which I think is much cleaner).

```
type
  CustomTuple = tuple
    foo: proc(input: int): int

proc createCustomTuple(): CustomTuple =
  (foo: proc(input: int): int {.closure.} = 10)
```

If you don't want to do either of these you can assign the proc to the `foo` property of the implicit `result` variable as per Salewski's answer.

This also explains why Salewski's original solution of assigning the proc to the `foo` property of the implicit `result` variable worked; the compiler is able to automatically convert the proc to a closure in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
type
  CustomObject = object
    foo: proc(input: int): int

proc createCustomObject(): CustomObject =
  #(foo: proc(input: int): int = 10)
  #result.foo = proc(input: int): int = 10
  CustomObject(foo: proc(input: int): int = input * 2)

var x = createCustomObject()
echo x.foo(2)
```

Comment: +1 This provides a solution that is functionally equivalent but doesn't actually explain why my original code fails to compile which is what I'm really interested in understanding.

Comment: Note that this solution also doesn't require us to say `result.foo = ...` which just highlights that there is something different going on when using custom tuples.